# How to split values from an array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to split values from an array with '|' separator.
The values split would be written adding one more column

```
UID     NAME    MTD DEVICE  APPLICATION APPLICATION REV
ABC     Melanie 10230   1520    google |mozilla 1.2|4
COCO    Ronald  222222  2682    explorer|ecosia 2.0|3
ZERTY   Cecilia 55555   634     google|ecosia   1.001|2.02
```

to:

```
UID     NAME    MTD     USAGE   DEVICE  APPLICATION APPLICATION REV 
ABC     Melanie 10230   1520    google  mozilla 1.2 4
COCO    Ronald  222222  2682    explorer ecosia 2   3
ZERTY   Cecilia 55555   634     google  ecosia  1.001   2.02
```

I tried function split, but I cannot replace get the whole range values. Here I can only split one cell.

```
function Separate() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet29');
    var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    var lc = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet29');
    var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, sheet1.getLastRow(), 13);
    var values1 = range1.getValues();;

    var cellToSplit = [];

    cellToSplit = spreadsheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValue();

    Logger.log(cellToSplit);
    var cellArray = cellToSplit.split("|"); // Splits the cell value by ',' and stores it in array.
    Logger.log(cellArray); //Array of 2 values  

    for (var i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(cellArray[i]); //Separate only one cell 
    }
```

Comment: sorry i wanted to past a tab that looked good on edit, i see how messy it is now lol

Comment: I understand you want to separate each value to write it later in a cell, right?

Comment: yes that's it. the one that have " | "

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to split all the values instead of only "|". First, use the split() function as you said, but like this:

```
  var values =  spreadsheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValue();
  var cellTosplit =  values.split(/[\s| ]+/); //here we separate by spaces and by |
```

As you want to write them again in the sheet, an option would be to store the cells in a 2D array:

```
  var array2d = [[],[]];

  var pos = 0; //position of the cells array    


    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {

      array2d[y] = []; 

      for (var x = 0; x <= columns; x++) { 

        array2d[y][x] = cellsTosplit[pos]; //Or you can use this loop to directly write the values in the range you want instead, instead of using the 2D array
        pos++;  
    }


   }
```

Now you can write the `array2d[row][column]` in the cells you need. As I said, you can make another foor loop to iterate over the Range and use `setValues(array2d[y][x])`, or use the same loop instead of the 2D array.